# Error while installing seabios (syntax error near unexpected token `newline')

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-os, chromebook

I can't install `seabios` even with the help of all the guides on how to install it.

I type in the following command (one line):

```
cd; rm -f flash_chromebook_rom.sh; curl -L -O https://johnlewis.ie/flash_chromebook_rom.sh; sudo -E bash flash_chromebook_rom.sh
```

I get the following error:

```
flash_chromebook_rom.sh: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
flash_chromebook_rom.sh: line 1: `<!DOCTYPE html>'
```

I tested and the error turns out to be in the final part:
The error is in the final part:

sudo -E bash flash_chromebook_rom.sh

Can somebody please help!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try adding quotes around the URL and a semicolon at the end:

```
cd; rm -f flash_chromebook_rom.sh; curl -L -O "https://johnlewis.ie/flash_chromebook_rom.sh"; sudo -E bash flash_chromebook_rom.sh;
```

Comment: Good idea but didn't work.
The error is in the final part:

sudo -E bash flash_chromebook_rom.sh

Comment: @Uio443 do you have a link I could see the source of the flash_chromebook_rom.sh file?

Answer (score 0):

The file has been relocated.

**The correct recipe is currently:** `cd;bash <(curl https://johnlewis.ie/flash_cb_fw.sh)`

The file that you tried to access no longer exists, and so consequently you downloaded the html for a missing page: https://johnlewis.ie/flash_chromebook_rom.sh.

`bash` is meant to run shell scripts (i.e. file.sh), so when it instead gets a blank template html file it throws an error.

If you search your home directory you should find the file *flash_chromebook_rom.sh*. Try changing the extension to *.html* and open it with Firefox; you will see a something like **Oops! That page can't be found.**

So the problem wasn't with `bash`; it was that `curl` didn't get the right file.

If this new recipe no longer works. The filename/recipe may have changed yet again. Please check https://johnlewis.ie/custom-chromebook-firmware/rom-download/ for updates, and kindly edit them into this answer.